# How do I avoid conflicting policy errors when deleting service account policies on GCP with terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am trying to use Terraform with GCP to create a service account and bind it to two roles.

Here is the Terraform:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      version = "~> 3.90.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  project = var.project_id
}

resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  account_id   = "bacalhau-duckdb-example-sa"
  display_name = "Bacalhau DuckDB Example Service Account"
}

data "google_iam_policy" "sa_iam_binding" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"
    members = [
      "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account.email}",
    ]
  }
}

resource "google_project_iam_policy" "sa_iam_policy" {
  project     = var.project_id
  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.sa_iam_binding.policy_data
  depends_on  = [google_service_account.service_account]
}

data "google_iam_policy" "storage_iam_binding" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/storage.admin"
    members = [
      "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account.email}",
      "user:aronchick@busted.dev"
    ]
  }
}

resource "google_project_iam_policy" "storage_iam_policy" {
  project     = var.project_id
  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.storage_iam_binding.policy_data
  depends_on  = [google_project_iam_policy.sa_iam_policy]
}
```

And here is the error:

```
...
google_compute_instance.gcp_instance["europe-west9-b"]: Destruction complete after 57s
google_project_iam_policy.storage_iam_policy: Destroying... [id=bacalhau-duckdb-example]
google_project_iam_policy.storage_iam_policy: Destruction complete after 1s
google_project_iam_policy.sa_iam_policy: Destroying... [id=bacalhau-duckdb-example]
╷
│ Error: Error setting IAM policy for project "bacalhau-duckdb-example": googleapi: Error 409: There were concurrent policy changes. Please retry the whole read-modify-write with exponential backoff. The request's ETag '\007\005\374\337\256Ja\010' did not match the current policy's ETag '\007\005\374\354\271jN\307'., aborted
│
│
╵
```

I should note that this only happens on destroy, and only happens once (if i destroy again, no errors. And no errors on creation).

Comment: Is the `last depends_on` correct? I think it should be `depends_on  = [google_service_account.service_account]`.

Comment: You have two `google_project_iam_policy` resources. Maybe you have hit a bug. Try merging both of the `google_iam_policy` into one, so that you are only declaring one resource. The issue is that policy changes must be a read-modify-write. The tag value is used to prevent overlapping writes. The two resources might be triggering that issue.

Comment: my thought was that by doing cascading `depends_on` it would force one to finish, and then the second could start - thereby removing the issue. I'll try to merge them.